# ExtJS - Error in IE retrieving data

Tags: javascript, extjs, fiddler

I have a rather strange problem. I have a grid setup and on row double click it pulls back data from that record and opens a new window, and that window fills in all the details.

Everything works fine on my dev box, but on the server (asp.net/IIS6) IE fails and FF works fine. However, here is the catch. I fired up Fiddler to try and see if I could sniff out the error from IE, and when Fiddler is running IE works fine. If I shut it down, it blows up again.

The error is ErrorCode: 400 and I have no idea how to debug it at this point due to it working when Fiddler is running.

Any thoughts?

Comment: When I have javascript problems specific to IE, the first thing I try is http://www.jslint.com/ I have no idea on the fiddler thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP/400 means "bad request" which suggests that the HTTP request was invalid in some way. You might try looking in the server's log for more information, and if that doesn't help, try capturing the raw HTTP error details using Netmon: http://www.fiddler2.com/redir/?id=netmon

Comment: I found the error, it was the way I was defining the store in Ext, but your answer got me started in the right direction. Thanks.